# How to separate 2 words with explode() in to 2 different strings

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, explode

I'm using a jQuery range slider for a price range, but even with `explode()` I can't separate the two prices (min and max) so I can use them with MySQL `BETWEEN`. Is there any way to do fix it (or a better way to pass data in to a query)?

At the end I would like to have two strings (`$price_min` & `$price_max`) so it is easy to use them.

Now it looks like this:

```
β¬500 - β¬878
```

However should be more like this:

```
€500 - €878
```

but the euro sumbol seems to have a problem.

Comment: Which charset do you use?

Comment: Do it in php after getting the myself results and before passing them to js

Comment: is your given string what the .val() of the range is? what language you have in backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why explode isn't working for you, here it is working:
https://eval.in/94159

```
$string = "β¬500 - β¬878";

$ary = explode("-",$string);

$min =  filter_var($ary[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$max =  filter_var($ary[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

echo "between " . $min . " and " .$max;
```